# Can I specify the labels in subclasses when using GQLAlchemy and Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

My issue is a large number of inherited labels. Sometimes there are quite a few superclasses and I don't want to inherit all labels. Is it possible, when using the Python OGM in GQLAlchemy, to specify the labels manually in subclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify labels when creating a class like this:

```
class Streamer(User, labels=["Twitcher", "Streamer"]):
```

There exist keyword `labels` and it should override class names.